# Rails 7, return active record association with two separate conditions, one in the parent, one in the child

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-7

I have an `Applicant` model, that has become the location or a chat between a project owner and an applicant to that project.

I track the applicant by using an `applicant.user` reference in the `Applicant` table.

I track the project owner by using `applicant.project.user`, which is a reference in the `Project` table (a parent of `Applicant`).

As I say, the `Applicant` table also has a child of `Messages`, and `Applicant` is essentially a chat view between two users.

Users are managed using Devise.

One other field to mention in the Applicant table is a `last_message` field, that gets updated whenever a user creates a new message for that `Applicant` record.

```
class Applicant < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy
end
```

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :applicants, dependent: :destroy
  has_rich_text :description
end
```

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :projects, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :applicants, dependent: :destroy
  has_rich_text :about

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable, :trackable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
end
```

```
class Message < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :applicant
end
```

I want to get a list of any users 'chats' (or Applicants). This is both their projects and their applicants.

I am currently doing this:

```
project_messages = []

current_user.projects.each do |project|
  project.applicants.each do |applicant|
    project_messages << applicant
  end
end

@chats = Applicant
  .where(id: (current_user.applicants + project_messages)
  .map(&:id))
  .order(last_message: :desc)
```

Here I get a list of the current_user projects and add each applicant (chat room) into an array. I then add this to the current_user.applicants. Then I merge both together as an Active record association.

This works, but I feel that it is a bad way to do this. Does anybody know a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: @mechnicov sure, added them now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join applicants and projects tables and check if current user is applicant or project "owner" like this

```rb
applicants =
  Applicant
    .joins(:project)
    .where('applicants.user_id = :id OR projects.user_id = :id', id: current_user.id)
    .order(last_message: :desc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can skip the looping and can add a custom association in User model like

```
class User
  has_many :other_chats, through: :projects, class_name: "Applicant"
end
```

and then you can query all the chats using

```
@chats = Applicant
  .where(id: (current_user.applicants + other_chats)
  .map(&:id)).order(last_message: :desc)
```

Comment: Probably undefined method or variable `other_chats` error will be. Three queries will executed. And probably if there are tons of applicants, `+` and `map` will be not so efficient